# Why is it removing first two words after loop runs? MIPS Mars Assembly

Tags: debugging, assembly, mips, mars-simulator

doing a project for university in MIPS Assembly.

I am doing a project and am storing 5 city names in a word called "array_cidades"
For each city, I'm asking the user a int temperature, and checking if it is odd or even.
I am using 3 arrays actually, and one index ($t0) to store and access each element.

My question is, why after this code runs, if I loop through my "array_cidades", it won't show me cidade_1 and cidade_2, like they have gone missing and I don't understand why...

```
.data

    array_temperaturas: .space 20 
    array_cidades: .word cidade_1, cidade_2, cidade_3, cidade_4, cidade_5
    array_even_odd: .word 20
    cidade_1: .asciiz "Porto - "
    cidade_2: .asciiz "Lisboa - "
    cidade_3: .asciiz "Faro - "
    cidade_4: .asciiz "Coimbra - "
    cidade_5: .asciiz "Viseu - "
    media: .asciiz "\nMedia: "
    minimo: .asciiz "\nMinimo: "
    maximo: .asciiz "\nMaximo: "
    nova_linha: .asciiz "\n"
    hashtag: .asciiz "#"
    estrela: .asciiz "*"
.globl main
.text
    main:
    # Index array = 0
    addi $t0, $zero, 0
    
    
    
    #For each temperature, gonna save it in the array, and save if it's odd or even
    foreach:
        bgt $t0, 16, limpar_index # Check if index > 16 (because 5 cities at [0,4,8,12,16])
        
        # Get city name to $t7
        lw $t7, array_cidades($t0)
        
        # Print city name at $t7
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, ($t7)
            syscall
            
            # Get user temperature
            li $v0, 5
            syscall
            
            # Save user input in array of temperatures
        move $t6, $v0
        sw $t6, array_temperaturas($t0) 
        
        # Check if user input is odd or even, stores in $t5
        andi $t5 , $t6 , 0x0001 
        sw $t5, array_even_odd($t0) # Saves it in the array
            
            # Prints new line
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, nova_linha
            syscall
                # Adds 4 to the array index (get next element)
                addi $t0, $t0, 4 # Index incrementado por 4 (proximo valor)
            j foreach
```

So, after this code runs it will branch to limpar_index tag. If i loop through, and print array_cidades, the first and second elements won't show up...

```
limpar_index:
   addi $t0, $zero, 0 # Index = 0

   test_start: # Printing the array_cidades
      bgt $t0, 16, text_exit
      
      # Print city
      li $v0, 4
      lw $a0, array_cidades($t0)
      syscall
        
      addi $t0, $t0, 4 #Increments array
        
      j test_start
        
text_exit: (...)
```

Any ideas why it's happening?

Comment: One debugging tool is to inspect the data before the program runs.  See if the addresses assigned make sense, and basically get to know you data.  Things can be wrong right there, and otherwise you'll know what good addresses look like for various data for single step debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 2 names are overwritten by 0x00000000 or 0x00000001.

```
array_even_odd: .word 20
```

means to allocate 4 bytes and put a value 20 there.

You may want to use

```
array_even_odd: .space 20
```

to allocate a 20-byte (5 4-byte elements) space.